# Why am I getting this msys64\clang64.exe error when building?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, c++20

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication6, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>clang-cl : error : no such file or directory: 'C:\msys64\clang64.exe'
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication6.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is msys64 something I'm supposed to have downloadeded for visual studio? I thought it might have been in my environment variables but I couldn't find it

Comment: 1. clang is not installed in specified folder 2. Was your intention to use clang anyway? If you using VisualStudio MSVC is expected (`cl` command). You've reconfigured something to change it to clang!

Comment: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/) is not something you normally download to work with Visual Studio Community.

Comment: Well now I'm confused; I've uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: I believe the problem is how you are generating your project or your settings in the project you have created. For some reason you are not using the msvc compiler and instead using clang. Visual Studio Community can use clang as an alternate compiler and has options for installing clang in the Visual Studio install but I can't help as I don't use that.